# php yii 2.0 new action in controller page not found 404

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using Yii 2.0 basic version and I need some help.
I created one ajax function like this:

```
function eliminarColaborador(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: "<?= urldecode(Url::toRoute(['colaborador/ajaxEliminarColaborador'])) ?>",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'id': id
        },
        complete: function ()
        {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data !== null)
            {
                // SUCCESS
            }
            else
            {
                // ERROR
            }

        }
    });
}
```

My action in controller:

```
public function actionAjaxEliminarColaborador($id) {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            $continuar = false;

            if(isset($id) && $id > 0) {                
                var_dump($model); die;

                $continuar = true;
            }


            echo CJSON::encode(array('continuar'=>$continuar));
            Yii::$app->end();
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this erro in firebug: Not Found (#404): Page not found.

I tried everything, but i can't figure out what's the problem.
If I change ajax url to **urldecode(Url::toRoute(['colaborador/delete']))** the error is gone and all works just fine.

Maybe I need to declare in ColaboradorController my new action **ajaxEliminarColaborador**, but I don't know how.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**controller**

```
public function actionAjaxEliminarColaborador(){}
```

**ajax**

```
urldecode(Url::toRoute(['colaborador/ajax-eliminar-colaborador']))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it works .. but now i'm getting **Forbidden (#403): You are not authorized to perform this action.**
Maybe it's related with this:
`public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow'   => true,
                        'actions' => ['index', 'view', 'update', 'delete', 'ajaxEliminarColaborador'],
                        'roles'   => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }` ?

Comment: I changed **ajaxEliminarColaborador** to **ajax-eliminar-colaborador** also in access rules like I said in last comment, and now it's working! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<?= urldecode(Url::toRoute(['colaborador/ajax-eliminar-colaborador'])) ?>`. [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#inline-actions) you can learn why.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ajax response with:

```
url: '/colaborador/ajaxEliminarColaborador/$id',
data: {id: $id,_csrf: yii.getCsrfToken()},
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to remove the word 'ajax' on your url.